# How can I use a mask in World Textures

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, world

I have a cycles world setup with 2 textures rendering out as equilateral (for 360 deg video). I would like to use either a mask shape or an object from the filed of view as a mask between the 2 textures.

[image: world textures setup, needs fac to drive mix]

I can use the dot product of a Normal node but its to hard to handle in multiples to create a square or other shape.